# How do I use a variable out of its scope

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

My problem is that I cannot use a variable out of it's scope. I am trying to make a typing based game. It will not let me use the variable "p2" out of an if statement. This is not the complete game, and I need to know how to use a variable out of an if statement. I am using JSfiddle. The HTML code is just a button to run the function.
Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function input() {
  var p = window.prompt("You wake up in a strange bed with a massive headache. There are two doors, one to the left, and one to the right. Which one would you like to go through?")
  if (p == "left") {
    var a1 = window.alert("You decided to go left. You walk up to what seems like another human. It was not. It tears you in half. You got the 'That ended fast' ending.")
    if (p = "right") {
      var p2 = window.prompt("You decided to go right. You look around and find a keycard! Two options: keep going straight or go left. Which direction would you like to go?")
    }
    if (p2 == "straight") {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The scope of variables declared with `var` is the entire function, not just the block it's declared in. However, the problem here is that unless you get to the inner `if`, you never assign anything to `p2`.

Comment: The second `if` should probably be using `a1`, not `p`.

Comment: If you're planning on implementing the entire game using nested `if` statements like this, it will become totally unmanageable. You need to come up with a more structured design, such as a state machine.

Comment: Why would you want to use `p2` outside the `if` statement, if you only assign to `p2` inside the `if` statement?

Comment: I want to use p2 out of the `if` because I can then add another ending or choice to make depending on what you type.

Comment: What problem are you having? If you use it out of the `if`, its value will be `undefined` and the comparison will fail as expected.

Comment: It says next to the p2 if statement that p2 can not be used out of its scope, but I guess it works anyway. I put something for it to do if p2 is equal to "straight" and it seemed to work anyway. It just says that p2 is used out of scope, and I cannot fix it

Comment: That's your IDE warning you, it's not coming from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your vars in root scope (current function), so they will be accessible in any child scopes (if statements). Here is example, I've corrected your logic a little just for example case.

```js
function input() {
  // Set variables
  let p, a1, p2;
  
  // Do your logic
  p = window.prompt("You wake up in a strange bed with a massive headache. There are two doors, one to the left, and one to the right. Which one would you like to go through?");
  if(p == "left") {
    a1 = window.alert("You decided to go left. You walk up to what seems like another human. It was not. It tears you in half. You got the 'That ended fast' ending.");
  }
  if(p == "right") {
    p2 = window.prompt("You decided to go right. You look around and find a keycard! Two options: keep going straight or go left. Which direction would you like to go?")
  }
  // Check p2
  if(p2 == "straight") {
      alert("Yes we go straight!");
  }
}

// Run fn
input();
```

Comment: Oh okay I was thinking that if I put the variables in the function's parenthesis or something like that it would work.